# How to load content fast with images loading in background?

Tags: ios, json, nsurlconnection

I want to make image load in background and let content load first. I tried below code but didnt work. What is wrong? Help me.
Thank you in advance.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"site.com/json.php"]];
   [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
   NSError *myError = nil;
   NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

   self.recipes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
   for(NSDictionary *dic in res){
       Recipe *recipe = [[Recipe alloc] init];
       recipe.name = [dic objectForKey:@"title"];

        recipe.imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"site.com/iphone_images/%@",[dic objectForKey:@"imageName"]];


       [recipes addObject:recipe];

       [myTableView reloadData];
   }
}
```

Comment: Add please your image loading code.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  First get content (which you need) and url of all the images , show all the content and then start downloading of all image in the background

Comment: I think your solution is not working because you are lack of essential knowledge about working with multiple threads. first you should read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html, if you are still stuck, present your solution for discussion.

Comment: @holex, i will go through it. The way i have done is mentioned bellow. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First get content (which you need) and url of all the images , show all the content and then start downloading of all image in  background.

Answer (score 0):

Please use AFNetworking to download the contents,also to download the images in the background ,AFNetworking comes with the UIImageView category which would be very much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code that is part of a complete downloadable example showing how to put up a UITableView, download the related images in the background, and add them to the table when they arrive:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch24p842downloader/ch37p1099downloader/MyTableViewController.m