# how to reload collectionViewCell in dispatch_async?

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, dispatch

collectionView reloadData not working. what is wrong in the code? if my question is not enough to understand, i have mentioned detail in this link
[How to load content fast with images loading in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22117887/how-to-load-content-fast-with-images-loading-in-background)
Thank you in advance

```
-(void)setMovieDetail{
    dispatch_async(bgQue, ^{

        //code here..
        [collectionView reloadData];

    });
}
```

Comment: UIKit methods need to be called on the main thread.

Comment: I have called UIKIT method in header file. But not working..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
[collectionView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData)
                                 withObject:nil
                              waitUntilDone:false];
```

Comment: Yes, i have tried too. But doesnt work. I even tried using this dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[collectionView reloadData}); but not working.

Comment: please have a look on my question in this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22117887/how-to-load-content-fast-with-images-loading-in-background